# How do I bypass a same origin policy violation for one local file to another?

Tags: javascript, security, html, canvas, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to semi-recreate Mozilla's [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/manipulating_video_using_canvas) usage of JavaScript + `<video>` + `<canvas>` with files that aren't hosted on a server.

Loading my document causes the error console to report this error:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "file:///media/disk/javascript/html5/chromakey/chromakey1.htm Line: 23"]

Here's line 23:

```
this.referenceImageData = this.bCtx.getImageData(0, 0, this.bufferCanvas.width, this.bufferCanvas.height);
```

It's trying to get the image data from a canvas to which I previously copied a frame of video like this:

```
this.bCtx.drawImage(this.inputElement,
    0, 0,
    this.inputElement.width, this.inputElement.height,
    0, 0,
    this.bufferCanvas.width, this.bufferCanvas.height
);
```

Where `this.inputElement` references this (fairly boring) element:

```
<video id="MainInput" src="320x240.ogg" width="320" height="240"></video>
```

Is there any way to get past this error without signing my code with a JAR?

I think it has to do with Firefox's same origin policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) having an issue local file access, but I can't figure out where to go from there.

Answer (score 4):

From the filesystem, each file is in a different origin (this prevents accessing e.g. `/etc/passwd` –let's say using an `XMLHttpRequest` or an `iframe`, and then pass data to some server on the Web using the query-string when loading an `<img>` or automatically sending a form though javascript). See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-abarth-origin (it talks about "implementation-defined value", and the easiest is to have a distinct origin per file)

The easiest way to workaround your issue is to run an HTTP server.

There might be a solution using [Firefox's "per-file permission"](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/per-file.html) but I'm not sure it's really worth it given how cheap it is to run a local HTTP server... (YMMV)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the file from the same origin, and I think that the file:// protocol is very restricted for obvious security reasons.

Only extensions could access these files, with more privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's origin policy for file access can be changed in "about:config". 
To eliminate the same origin policy on file: URIs, change the "true" value of
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false.[Mozilla;about:config;origin_policy setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jToLD.jpg)