# How to fetch image from system to load in canvas in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following way:-

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
   body {
     margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
   }
   #myCanvas {
     border: 1px solid #9C9898;
   }
  </style>
 <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
    };
    imageObj.src = "C:\Images\Demo.jpg";
  };

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to load this image in canvas. Is it right way to pass image URL in imageObj.src ?

or is there any other way to load the image ?

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it nearly right.  If you are loading the file locally, you need to prefix your path with `file:///`:

```
imageObj.src = "file:///C:/Images/Demo.jpg";  // also, use forward slashes, not backslashes
```

I think all browsers will require you to have the image stored in the same directory as or in a subdirectory from the current HTML page, so that local HTML pages can't go grabbing things from all over your hard drive.

I'd suggest you make the path relative to your current HTML document.  If the page is at `file:///C:/Users/shanky/webpages/page.html` then just use:

```
imageObj.src = "img/Demo.jpg";
```

to load an image located at `file:///C:/Users/shanky/webpages/img/Demo.jpg`.  This makes it easier if you move your page to a new folder or host it on a server, where it no longer uses the `file:` protocol.

Note that most browsers are pretty finicky about the [same origin policy for `file:` resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040724/how-do-i-bypass-a-same-origin-policy-violation-for-one-local-file-to-another).  It may be easier to host your application on a simple local server and access it with `http://localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for answer apsillers, this works for me now correctly.but when i am using this property it gets faliure.        var imageData = context.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1); mx and my are mouse position

Comment: @Shanky Glad I could help. Unfortunately, I think that follow-up question about `getImageData` is too complex to give a quick answer to in the comments. In general on Stack Overflow, if you have a new problem with your program, just open a new question!

Comment: And, just a wild guess -- maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040724/how-do-i-bypass-a-same-origin-policy-violation-for-one-local-file-to-another) will solve your problem?  Again, you should open a new question, but maybe that link will give you a starting point for asking your new question (or help you solve your problem totally by yourself).

Comment: I have found solution for that. But how can i load image with th help of http:localhost

Comment: user can also select image from any directory. Then how can i get relative path of that file. or the other way is to copy file in my desired folder. Then i pick image from that folder.