# inserting image in html canvas code not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i'm trying to insert an image in a canvas but my code does'nt seem to work. i'm getting a canvas with the appropriate background color but somehow the image does not get displayed. here is my code.
    
    
        Character on canvas
        
        .canvas1
        {
            background-color:grey;
            border:1px solid;
        }

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imagediv">
        <img id="spear1" src="E:\html-files\spear.png" style="height:150px; width:150px" draggable="true" ondrag="drag()" >
    </div>
    <div id="canvasdiv">
        <canvas id="mainCanvas" class="canvas1" height="500px" width="600px"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        var canvas=document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img=document.getElementById("spear1");
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,160,160);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch image from system to load in canvas in html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644192/how-to-fetch-image-from-system-to-load-in-canvas-in-html5)

Comment: You can drawImage, also from external location. You can't do "getImageData" though. But the problem here is that the image might not have been completely loaded yet

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4TfC/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert an image in a canvas, the image must have been loaded before inserted,so your code maybe look like that:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("spear1");
img.onload = function(){
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,160,160);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to link the image with a **relative path**, or directly to an http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/5L7uL/.

Here is an example of [linking to a file stored online](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/5L7uL/1/)

```
<img id="spear1" src="http://jamesmcgillis.com/upload/google_logo_001_small.jpg"...
```

*If it does not work for you, make sure your browser supports canvas* :-)